# Problem of upgrading Angular from 6 to 7 in my ASP.net MVC project, help needed

Tags: angular, upgrade

I have an ASP.net MVC project using Angular framework 6. I try to upgrade Angular from 6 to 7 following the guide of https://update.angular.io/?l=3&v=6.1-7.0

When I run the command below

```
cmd /C "set "NG_DISABLE_VERSION_CHECK=1" && npx @angular/cli@7 update @angular/cli@7 @angular/core@7"
```

I got the error message:

```
Your global Angular CLI version (7.3.10) is greater than your local
version (6.2.9). The local Angular CLI version is used.

To disable this warning use "ng config -g cli.warnings.versionMismatch false".
                  Package "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" has a missing peer dependency of "@angular/compiler" @ "7.2.16".
                  Package "@angular/router" has a missing peer dependency of "@angular/platform-browser" @ "7.2.16".
                  Package "@angular/forms" has a missing peer dependency of "@angular/platform-browser" @ "7.2.16".
Incompatible peer dependencies found. See above.
```

If I try

```
ng update @angular/cli@7.2.16 @angular/core@7.2.16 --force
```

Here is what I got

```
Package "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic" has a missing peer dependency of "@angular/compiler" @ "7.2.16".
                  Package "@angular/forms" has a missing peer dependency of "@angular/platform-browser" @ "7.2.16".
                  Package "@angular/router" has a missing peer dependency of "@angular/platform-browser" @ "7.2.16".
    Updating package.json with dependency zone.js @ "0.8.29" (was "0.8.26")...
    Updating package.json with dependency rxjs @ "6.6.7" (was "6.2.2")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/core @ "7.2.16" (was "6.1.10")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/platform-browser-dynamic @ "7.2.16" (was "6.1.7")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/common @ "7.2.16" (was "6.1.7")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/forms @ "7.2.16" (was "6.1.7")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/language-service @ "7.2.16" (was "6.1.7")...
    Updating package.json with dependency @angular/router @ "7.2.16" (was "6.1.7")...
UPDATE package.json (1802 bytes)
npm ERR! code ERESOLVE
npm ERR! ERESOLVE could not resolve
npm ERR!
npm ERR! While resolving: client-app@0.0.0
npm ERR! Found: @angular/common@6.1.7
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!   @angular/common@"^7.2.16" from the root project
npm ERR!   peer @angular/common@">=6.0.0-beta.0 <7.0.0" from @angular/cdk@6.4.7
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/cdk
npm ERR!     peer @angular/cdk@"6.4.7" from @angular/material@6.4.7
npm ERR!     node_modules/@angular/material
npm ERR!       @angular/material@"^6.1.0" from the root project
npm ERR!   9 more (@angular/forms, @angular/material, ...)
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Could not resolve dependency:
npm ERR! @angular/common@"^7.2.16" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Conflicting peer dependency: @angular/core@7.2.16
npm ERR! node_modules/@angular/core
npm ERR!   peer @angular/core@"7.2.16" from @angular/common@7.2.16
npm ERR!   node_modules/@angular/common
npm ERR!     @angular/common@"^7.2.16" from the root project
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Fix the upstream dependency conflict, or retry
npm ERR! this command with --force or --legacy-peer-deps
npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution.
npm ERR!
npm ERR!
npm ERR! For a full report see:
npm ERR! C:\Users\rrao\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-21T19_57_25_233Z-eresolve-report.txt

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: C:\Users\rrao\AppData\Local\npm-cache\_logs\2023-12-21T19_57_25_233Z-debug-0.log
Package install failed, see above.
```

Comment: Try just using `--force` on the update and then update the peer dependencies if they aren't updated.

Comment: You mean "ng update @angular/cli@7.2.16 @angular/core@7.2.16 --force" ?

Comment: Just tried "ng update @angular/cli@7.2.16 @angular/core@7.2.16 --force" and got some other errors (shown in edited content)

Comment: What is your version of node when you try the update? If you're using the right version of node, try updating each dependency using `--force`.

Comment: Really confused of what those error messages mean and what should I do to resolve.

Comment: Some of those dependencies are beta and there were probably big changes. It doesn't help that your app is ancient to find good community advice. I understand the confusion, but you'll just have to push through and you'll eventually get all the peer dependencies alligned. You could do it manually in your project.json, but you want to try using the update commands first. It helps with not having to make manual changes to the app to get things to work again, which would be even more confusing.

Comment: It is a project created years ago when Angular 6 was still popular. I need to upgrade Angular from 6 to 17. 6 to 7 is only the first step and it already drove me crazy.

Comment: The latest updates, 14 through 17, should go a lot smoother. I hope that can be a small relief.

Answer (score 0):

Try running the updates separately with `--force`:

> npx ng update @angular/cli@7.2.16 --force

> npx ng update @angular/core@7.2.16 --force

> npx ng update @angular/common@7.2.16 --force

> npx ng update @angular/forms@7.2.16 --force

> npx ng update @angular/router@7.2.16 --force

... and whatever other dependencies that still need to update

*Make sure to use the right node version, as stated in the angular update documentation you are using.*

Comment: If the app isn't proprietary I'm willing to give it a shot, if you can share the repo.

Comment: Thanks. Appreciated. I was actually using node 20 instead of node 10. I will try to downgrade my node version and do it again

Comment: Uninstalled node 20 and installed node 10. 
run 'ng update @angular/cli@7.2.16 --force'
got message below:

Node.js version v10.0.0 detected.
The Angular CLI requires a minimum Node.js version of v18.13.
Please update your Node.js version or visit https://nodejs.org/ for additional instructions.

Comment: I wish I could share the code. But it is proprietary and it also uses other proprietary libraries.
I feel that it might be easier to create a new project with the latest Angular and .Net Core, then porting all the codes there.

Comment: @RRAO Use npx to run local packages iso global.

Comment: Did it and got a lot of warnings asking me to upgrade npm version. Then the following erros in the end:
npm ERR! path C:\Projects\Web\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd
npm ERR! code EEXIST
npm ERR! Refusing to delete C:\Projects\Web\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd: is outside C:\Projects\Web\node_modules\typescript and not a link
npm ERR! File exists: C:\Projects\Web\node_modules\.bin\tsc.cmd
npm ERR! Move it away, and try again.

Comment: I moved tsc.cmd away and tried it again. Got different error:
npx: installed 1 in 1.341s
The "path" argument must be of type string. Received type undefined
null